# Unable to locate Google Maps API key for installed Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I've completed the application form for a Google Maps API key for my Android application, having supplied the package name and the SHA1 key (from my debug.keystore) successfully (it accepted the data and returned to the opening page) but I can't see the API key. I can see a  "Simple API Access Use API keys to identify your project when you do not need to access user data." but of course, that doesn't work in the app.

I don't think I'm revealing any confidential data in the attached screen shot:

[image: Screen Shot]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was going down the wrong path!
It was as simple as clicking on the "Create New Android Key" button - I pressed the OAuth button.